# Como agrupar informações em um data frame a partir de dados faltantes?

Tags: r, dplyr, dataframe

Preciso excluir as linhas vazias do df de uma serie temporal de 30 anos, com três medições diárias para cada variável. Já empreguei a função `subset(x, ...)` que resolve parte do problema. Porém, em alguns casos não há nenhuma medição registrada, como observado na coluna "prec" para a data "1961-08-21". Nesse caso, preciso manter uma linha indicando que não foi realizada medição naquele dia, isto é, que permaneça com NA. Como posso fazer isso?

```
date        id      prec    tair    tw      tmax    tmin
1961-08-21  83377   NA      22.6    14.1    27.9    NA
1961-08-21  83377   NA      23.8    15.2    NA      13.8
1961-08-21  83377   NA      24.2    15.4    NA      NA
1961-08-22  83377   NA      22.6    14.1    29.7    NA
1961-08-22  83377   0       24.8    14.6    NA      13.9
1961-08-22  83377   NA      27      16      NA      NA
1961-08-23  83377   NA      24.6    14      28.8    NA
1961-08-23  83377   1       19.8    14.6    NA      13.8
1961-08-23  83377   2       18.8    14.7    NA      13.6
```

Comment: Não percebo o problema. Precisa de manter **só uma** linha para o dia `"1961-08-21"` em vez de três linhas? Se sim, o que fazemos das outras colunas? Pode dar um exemplo da saída correspondente a estes dados?

Comment: Preciso de uma serie temporal continua, sem datas duplicadas ou faltantes. Se aplico subset(x, ...) na coluna prec, por exemplo, vou perder informação desse dia para essa variável, enquanto que para as demais colunas eu terei um valor médio entre as três medições (que eu também não consegui automatizar). Assim o meu conjunto de dados será diferente para cada coluna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá pra resolver este problema com o pacote `dplyr`:

```
dados <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
 .Label = c("1961-08-21", "1961-08-22", "1961-08-23"), class = "factor"), 
 id = c(83377L, 83377L, 83377L, 83377L, 83377L, 83377L, 83377L, 83377L, 83377L), 
 prec = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L), 
 tair = c(22.6, 23.8, 24.2, 22.6, 24.8, 27, 24.6, 19.8, 18.8), 
 tw = c(14.1, 15.2, 15.4, 14.1, 14.6, 16, 14, 14.6, 14.7), 
 tmax = c(27.9, NA, NA, 29.7, NA, NA, 28.8, NA, NA), 
 tmin = c(NA, 13.8, NA, NA, 13.9, NA, NA, 13.8, 13.6)), 
 .Names = c("date", "id", "prec", "tair", "tw", "tmax", "tmin"), 
 class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -9L))

library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(Media=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  date       id_Media prec_Media tair_Media tw_Media tmax_Media tmin_Media
  <fct>         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1961-08-21   83377.     NaN          23.5     14.9       27.9       13.8
2 1961-08-22   83377.       0.         24.8     14.9       29.7       13.9
3 1961-08-23   83377.       1.50       21.1     14.4       28.8       13.7
```

Basicamente, eu agrupei os dados de acordo com a data e calculei a média de cada uma das outras colunas. Perceba que também calculei a média de `id`, mas como imagino que os `id` sejam iguais para cada data, tanto faz calcular esta média ou não.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Funcionou. Se ao invés da media eu precisar da soma ou de um valor específico entre os três, por exemplo, do segundo valor atribuído à data 1961-08-21, também posso aplicar o pacote [dplyr]  então?

Comment: Sim. Basta substituir `mean` pela função adequada a cada caso. É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.